# how to retrieve archived files

Tags: macos

I have MacBookAir and all my downloaded files are going into Download dir. I see that there are nothing older than June 1, 2019 in the Download dir, however. I have important document that i downloaded in March of 2019 and i can't figure out on how to retrieve it if even possible.

It is my conclusion that the files are being archived by the Mac automatically.

How do i retrieve the files older than the June 1, 2020 or any info would help on how it is being automatically deleted/archived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set up Time Machine to have backups. There is no archive process since that is different than backup.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201250

Short of you using time machine to look at that folder in the past, you would need to locate another copy of the file using spotlight in case you moved it to a different location.

Since you don’t mention your version, here is an article describing some clean up options.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206996

The system doesn’t purge any files unless you set that up, and then only in trash.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is very useful.